# Flutter build version code in debug mode and release mode not same

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can build the Flutter app with my expect:

Version code: `200008`
Version name: `2.0.8`

But, I try with my experience never successful, here are examples that I tried:

### 1. Try with the version in pubspec.yaml

```yaml
version: 2.0.8+200008
```

Result:

version code: 202008
version name: 2.0.8

### 2. Try with flutter tool in CLI

```sh
flutter build apk --build-name=2.0.8 --build-number=200008
```

Result:

version code: 202008
version name: 2.0.8

Please help me....

Comment: Did you run any of the following commands after first step? `flutter packages get`, `flutter build`, `flutter run`

Comment: Yes, i run command `flutter pub get`, `flutter run`, and `flutter build ..`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems to be works fine. How you check your version code and name? Can you check them with this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info/example).

Comment: No, when debug mode is fine, but when build to APK/ release not work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you built apk with parameters "--split-per-abi", so each apk has its own version code. Please refer to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions).

In this way, you need not fix it, because Play Store does not allow multiple apks for the same app have the same version information.